# customizing minor ticks with pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I am plotting some simple data using `pgfplots` on a log-log scale. My code is:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots, amsmath}

\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=newest}

\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/set thousands separator = }

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{loglogaxis}[
            xlabel =                            {A},
            ylabel =                            {B},
            ]
            \addplot[
            color =                             red,
            mark =                              x,
            ] 
            coordinates 
            {
                (20,2.8559703)
                (300,30.5301677)
                (4000,400.3050655)
                (50000,5000.1413136)
                (600000,60000.0322865)
                (7000000,600000.9675052)
                (80000000,7000000.9377747)
            };
        \end{loglogaxis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Code output]

There are two things I would like to change in the output:

I do not want the y axis labels to be two orders of 10 apart (this is the label spacing generated by default by the code), but would rather have them differ by one order of magnitude. I find that I can change this by including the line `extra y ticks={1e1, 1e3, 1e5},` in the options of `begin{loglogaxis} [options]`.

However, the logarithmically spaced minor tick marks on the y-axis do not appear as they do in the x-axis. Only the major tick marks appear at `10^0`, `10^1`, …, `10^6`.

[image: Minor tick marks are now missing on the y-axis]

How do I make these minor tick marks appear? I tried looking through the manual; I know the answer to my question is in there somewhere, but I am new to `pgfplots` and the huge number of options to customize ticks and labels is overwhelming!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) As new user without image posting privileges simply include the image as normal and remove the `!` in front of it to turn it into a link. A moderator or another user with edit privileges can then reinsert the `!` to turn it into an image again.

Comment: Does `ytickten = {0,...,6}` solve your problem?

Comment: Yes, this works!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [`pgfplots` manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgfplots), section 4.14 “Tick Options”, p. 241:

> `/pgfplots/ytickten={<exponent base 10 list>}`
>
> These options allow to
>   place ticks at selected positions 10<sup>*k*</sup>; *k* ∈
>   `{<exponent base 10 list>}`. They are only used for logplots. The
>   syntax for `{<exponent base 10 list>}` is the same as above for
>   `xtick={<list>}` or `ytick={<list>}`.
>
> Using `xtickten={1,2,3,4}` is
>   equivalent to `xtick={1e1,1e2,1e3,1e4}`, but it requires fewer
>   computational time and it allows to use the short syntax
>   `xtickten={1,...,4}`.

… and it adds back the minor “log-ticks” marks.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots, amsmath}

\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=newest}

\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/set thousands separator = }

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{loglogaxis}[
            xlabel   = {A},
            ylabel   = {B},
            ytickten = {0,...,6},
            ]
            \addplot[
            color = red,
            mark  = x,
            ] 
            coordinates 
            {
                (20,2.8559703)
                (300,30.5301677)
                (4000,400.3050655)
                (50000,5000.1413136)
                (600000,60000.0322865)
                (7000000,600000.9675052)
                (80000000,7000000.9377747)
            };
        \end{loglogaxis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image: Output]